# Shrink UIButton When Highlighted

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a button which is built in with my own custom image.  I want to give feedback to the user that it has been clicked by shrinking it when it's highlighted.  As of now, I'm thinking of making a smaller scale of the  image to replace the original when the button is highlighted.  But I'm wondering if there's another solution to shrink the size of the button image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the image on the button?  If it is a sepperate image that u want to shrink when the button is pressed then u could do this
If the image is the button then it is impossible to do this without just changing images. or putting the image behind the button.

do this if u are going to put the image in the background

```
-(IBAction)Shrink:(id)sender{
     Image.frame = MakeCCGRectMake(position x, position y, size x, size y);

}
```

and change the sent events from touch up inside to touch down

Comment: The image is the button.  I set the image of the button in utilities in interface builder.  I also want to tell u that I want it to shrink when it's highlighted not after it's clicked -- I'll clarify in post.

Comment: Ahh, touch down, that is what I'm looking for.